# Visual Studio 2017 cannot add file to local cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, visual-studio-2017

I run Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise as Administrator and select File > Open > Web Site > FTP Site. I log in to the site using an IP Address, start directory and a username and password in Passive mode. After the site loads, I right click the App_Code folder and select Add New Item, I select class and name of NewClass.cs. When I click add, I get an error dialog box that says

Cannot add the file
'C:\Users\LP\AppData\Local\Temp\l1w5g2.k.0ho\Class.cs'
to the local cache. The system cannot find the path specified.

If I right click on the folder again and select Refresh folder it shows a file now called NewClass.cs. However, if I double click the file I get another error dialog box that says

Unable to get file 'NewClass.cs' from the Web server.

I cannot work on this website at all. I think I need to delete or clear the 'cache' but have no idea how to do that. The path mentioned above does not exist. Unsure how to make this project editable again.

Comment: Does a .vs folder get created? What happens if you delete that?

Comment: Make sure you same ALL before running.  The project is not saved so it is compiling in your TEMP folder.  Once you save the project you will be working in a real folder instead of temp space.

Comment: I have not seen a .vs folder created anywhere until I followed jdweng's advice and did a Save All. After saving all, everything started working again. Thank you for your help.